# Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC in linked list

Tags: visual-c++

i was trying to make the linked list with the following code 
typedef of string is char*

```
void insert_at_front(CourseList* self, String *course) {//inserting to the front

void insert_at_front(CourseList* self, String *course) {//inserting to the front
CourseNodePtr new = malloc(sizeof * new);
new->course=malloc(sizeof course+1);
strncpy_s(new->course, sizeof course+1, course, sizeof course+1);
new->students = new_bst();
new->next = self->head;
self->head = new;
```

}

how  ever i got error Exception thrown at 0x66C5FF80 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC when i am trying to enter any character or string in course. Just don't know what is wrong with the code.

update:
i have edited the code to this,it runs but nothing stored in course if i type in numbers. If i type in any characters, it loops and loops again.

```
void insert_at_front(CourseList* self, String* course) {//inserting to the front
CourseNodePtr new_node;


if (!(new_node = malloc(sizeof * new_node))) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(1);

    if (!(new_node->course = malloc(strlen(course) + 1))) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    strncpy_s(new_node->course, strlen(course) + 1, course, strlen(course) + 1);
    new_node->students = new_bst();
    new_node->next = self->head;
    self->head = new_node;
}
```

Comment: `new` is a reserved word in C++. You can not define a variable named `new`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `sizeof course` returns the size of the pointer (typically 4 or 8). It has no connection whatsoever to the size of the memory buffer that pointer points to.

Comment: Your updated code exits if the first `malloc` returns NULL, and does nothing at all (beside leaking memory) if that `malloc` succeeds.